# focus indicator stays on radio input even when I tab out to the next element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, radio-button, focus

When I tab into a radio button and select it then tab into the next element, the focus indicator stays on the initial radio button. I have looked everywhere for a solution but I cannot find out why this happens and I cannot replicate it by creating a new set of radio buttons. If anyone can please give me some help on this I could greatly appreciate it.

`<input name="mdnSelection" type="radio" id="check2" class="radioBtn" role="radio" aria-checked="true" aria-label="4G Smartphone PDI radio button checked" data-analyticstrack="select-upgradeDevice-radio" data-track="true" value="4702149611">`

[more code examples with CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52KjT.png)

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: Is there CSS involved?

Comment: Not that I can see, I will try to paste the code